# MIPS Synchronization with locks

Tags: synchronization, locking, mips

The slides for the "Computer Organization and Design" book show this code snippet as an example of acquiring a lock:

```
try: addi $t0,$zero,1 #copy locked value
ll $t1,0($s1) #load linked
sc $t0,0($s1) #store conditional
beq $t0,$zero,try #branch if store fails
#<< lock acquired >>
```

My understanding is that the `ll` instruction reads the initial value at a memory location and `sc` stores a value there only if the initial value read by `ll` has not been changed. So, if the initial value at the memory location was `1` meaning that the lock has been acquired by another processor, wouldn't this procedure simply override that value and assume it acquired the lock that way?

Comment: Note that `$t0` is used as `rt` for `sc`. If `sc` fails _" memory is not modified and a 0, indicating failure, is written into GPR `rt`"_. See the descriptions for `ll` and `sc` in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Comment: Yes, I realize that `sc` will store a `0` in `$t0` if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a missing branch conditional in your snippet. You should check whether the lock is already taken.

i.e.:

```
try: 
   addi $t0,$zero,1 #copy locked value
retry:
  ll $t1,0($s1) #load linked
  bnez $t1, retry # If lock taken, retry
  sc $t0,0($s1) #store conditional
  beq $t0,$zero,try #branch if store fails
#<< lock acquired >>
```

Comment: That would make sense and matches my understanding of how `ll` and `sc` work, but for some reason the slides fail to mention this and my professor claims it makes sense somehow.

Comment: Unless you have prior information about the status of the lock (i.e. you know somehow that the lock is not taken, or you want to "steal" the lock), you should check the lock.